# biblatex footcite style

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I'm currently using biblatex and biber for my bibliography. While using `bibstyle=alphabetic` and `citestyle=alphabetic` generates the desired output, I want to edit the footcite format.
As you might guess, at the moment it outputs something like this:

[image: both styles alphabetic]

I want to change the footcite format to be `verbose`. Setting `citestyle=verbose` solves the problem for the footnote but it also changes the citation in the text, what I don't want:

[image: citestyle verbose]

Is it possible to set `bibstyle=alphabetic`, `citestyle=alphabetic` and something like **`footcitestyle=verbose`**?

So the whole document should look like this (I used Photoshop in order to put this together):

[image: desired output]

How can I achieve this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{ford,
author = {Ford, Rebecca},
title  = {Earthquake: Twitter Users Learned of Tremors
          Seconds Before Feeling Them},
date   = {2011-08},
url    = {http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/earthquake-twitter-users-learned-tremors-226481}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, backref=true, citestyle=alphabetic, bibstyle=alphabetic, labeldate]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

It is true that \cite{ford} is wrong.

Citing in a footnote\footcite{ford} might be adventurous.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm rather certain that it can be done somehow. But why do you want to confuse your readers by using two different reference systems?

Comment: Good argument. I think that citing with `citestyle=verbose` in my text confuses the readers because it's hard to read the whole sentence. However, citing with `citestyle=alphabetic` in a footnote doesn't give the information I would expect in that place. But yeah, there might be different arguments and all are valid.

Comment: But why do you use \cite in the text at all? `\textcite` would be okay.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use \cite? I can't see any disadvantes, especially since it is mentioned in the official biblatex docs: ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: Because you are mixing two citing methods. Why are some in the footnote but other not?

Comment: That's right, I should have mentioned this. I want to use the footcite option only for figures or tables. I don't have that much experience with citing. Do you consider it as a bad practice to use footcite at all when citing in the normal text?

Comment: `\footnotes` in float  (figure and table) won't work - at least not if you expect them to appear at the bottom of the page.  `\footcite` in itself is ok as citation style, but I probably wouldn't use the verbose style. Or do you believe the readers are really interested in all the details when reading the text?

Comment: If you only want to use footnotes occasionally, just go with `\footfullcite` which should give a full citation in a footnote.

Answer (score 8):

For the sporadic full footnote citation you will want to use `\footfullcite`, which will give a full citation in the footnote.